# Execute Dispatch main in sequence

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

How to execute a set of dispatch codes in sequence.
For example :

```
Dispatch.main.async{
 //call API, it may takes 5-10 seconds..
 //do something..
   print("done 1")
}

Dispatch.main.async{
//call API, it may takes 5-10 seconds..
//do something
  print("done 2")
}

Dispatch.main.asyncAfter{
  print("completed")
}

Output:
 completed
 done1
 done2

Expected output:
 done1
 done2
 completed
```

I use the main because 'do something' is populate the resut to UI.
I tried to used global() but the 'completed' always executed first and not appropriate to use dispatch time delay since cannot confirm how long the API calling times. need a suggestion in swift ~

Comment: Why dont you use completion handler? Try it, lots of SO posts are available.

Comment: Since the main queue is a serial dispatch queue, you can use `Dispatch.main.async()` for your third block as well, or you can use a dispatch_group

Answer (score 0):

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async{
            //call API, it may takes 5-10 seconds..
            //do something..
            print("done 1")
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            //call API, it may takes 5-10 seconds..
            //do something
            print("done 2")
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1){
            print("completed")
        }
```

[image: It will execute in sequence]

Comment: This looks like it's working, but if `done 1` and `done 2` were actually taking 5-10 seconds, you would still print `completed` first

Comment: yes, just used this codes but can't get my expected result.Ideally i want to a chunk of code after all main dispatch are completed.